# Get only textboxes that value has changed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have user information that when I click the name from a gridview it populates data from SQL into text boxes. Data such as First Name, Last Name, Address , email, etc. I have about 30 textboxes and drop down lists.

I want to just get the values from the text boxes that the value has changed an update them in a sql query. For example: Only Middle Name and Address has changed so the query will only update this fields and not all 30 or so.

I tried this just to test and it does not work. Any ideas?

```
protected void btnUpdateChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbFirstName.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txt_TextChanged);
    tbLastName.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txt_TextChanged);
    tbMiddleName.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txt_TextChanged);
}

void txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = sender as TextBox;
    switch (txt.ID)
    {
        case "tbFirstName":
            lblMessage.Text = "First Name changed";
            break;
        case "tbLastName":
            break;
        case "tbMiddleName":
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to store the initial values somewhere and do a lookup against that and finally update the tables

Comment: "it does not work" is not good explanation. Side note: depending on your DB structure updating one vs. all fields may not show any performance differences.

Comment: @Rex - while it is good suggestion make sure to avoid reading values from DB first on every request if you decide to turn comment into an answer (store in Session state?).

Comment: @Rex I know you can store values in a variable. But if I have 100 textboxes I have to stored all 100 of them in a separate variable. I was just asking if there is a way just to get the one that have changed.

Comment: @Apollo You don't have to have 100 variables, make a DATATABLE OR LIST OR ARRAY.....

Answer (score 0):

Store initial values in a session variable and then update it and later update the database with the stored session on a click or something.

Answer (score 0):

Why not subclass the TextBox and have it tell if it has been modified?

Instead of textbox.Text = "some text" user myTextBox.SetText("some text");

Then just check the TextModified property to see if the current text is different than the original text.

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox {

    private string originalText = null;

    public MyTextBox()
        : base() {
    }

    public bool TextModified {
        get {
            if (this.OriginalText != this.Text) return true;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public string OriginalText {
        get { return this.originalText; }
        internal set { this.originalText = value; }
    }

    public void SetText(string text) {
        this.Text = text;
        this.OriginalText = text;
    }

}
```